# How to create views as a grid(such as 9*9 grid, 15*15 grid) by using for loops in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, uiimageview

I am trying to draw a 15*15 grid in Objective-C. The grid colour is blue which is like making the board of the "Snake" game in NOKIA.

I've tried using the for loop to create subviews but it seems not working, I looked over the internet and most of them are using UIImageView to make the grid, is there any solution for making a 15*15 grid with for loop or I have to use the `UIImageView` method?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

int i;
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
int firstColor=0;

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]== UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    cellWidth = 23;
    CellHeight= cellWidth;
    topY=230-4*CellHeight;
    leftX=110-4*cellWidth;
}else{

    cellWidth=46;
    CellHeight=cellWidth;
    topY=500-4*CellHeight;
    leftX=384-4*cellWidth;
}


UIView *viewA = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 414, 434)];
viewA.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:viewA];


for (int row = 0; row < rows; row = row++ ){
    for(int r = 0; r <= 414; r = r + 23){
    UIView *viewB = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(r,5,23,23)];
    viewB.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    [viewA addSubview:viewB];}}





col=col+1;
firstColor=1-firstColor;
if (col>18){
    row=row+1;
    firstColor=1-firstColor;
    col=0;
}
```

Comment: If you want help with your code, update your question with the relevant code. Explain what the exact issue is with the code you put in your question.

Comment: it depends!!!! you can simply put 15 uiviews, as a uiview can be a simple rectangle/squre . OR you can even go for collectionview!!!!  YOu should update your question with what you tried !!!

Comment: You want a single custom-draw UIView; not 15-subviews.

Comment: Hi i've just upload the code which cant make views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use bezierPath for drawing the custom view. If you need 3*3 grid layout, you need 9 bezier paths!!!!

YOu can achieve this kind of result by using bezier path:
[image]

YOu can even enter the rows/cols you need:

declare the properties in your view .h file:

```
   @property (assign) int row;
   @property (assign) int col;
```

and you can call the view from your view controller using:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    testView *tv = [[testView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 50, 100, 100)];

    tv.row = 3;
    tv.col = 4;

    [self.view addSubview:tv];
}
```

Here I assumed grid cell size as 20x20

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)frame {

    int x = 0, y = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= _row*_col; i++) {

            UIBezierPath* rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + x + 27, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + y + 13, 20, 20)];

            [UIColor.grayColor setFill];
            [rectanglePath fill];
            [UIColor.blackColor setStroke];
            rectanglePath.lineWidth = 1;
            [rectanglePath stroke];

            x = x + 20;

            if (i%_row == 0) {
                x = 0;
                y = y + 20;
            }

        }
}
```

You can playaround with the grid colors too!!!

Comment: Thank you for your helping, so if I want to create a 15*15 grid which means I have to draw 15* 15 rectangles individually? Is there any way to simplify it? Thank you.

Comment: i addded row and col implementation too @vincentfeng

Comment: where did you put that code?  you need to create two .h and .m files of class UIView and you need to put the code in drawRect method in the .m file of UIView class

Comment: Hi, I've tried put your code in but it shows one error which said that drawRect is an undeclared identifier(  -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)frame{
) I can use the drawRect in my other project but I don't know why this cannot work? I think I might missed something

Comment: I put it into the viewController.m

Comment: no, you shouldnt put it in viewcontroller!!! press command+N and create a new file of class UIView and name it as test and put the code in the drawRect method of the testVIew .m file

Comment: I created new .h and .m file, the 3*3 grid now shows up on the top left of the screen

Comment: yes. It is because you allocated the testVIew at (30,50) ....initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 50, 100, 100)];...which is top left on the screen. YOu need to update the values 30 and 50 according to your need

Comment: Hi, I tried your new code and I've declared the property in the .h file, and try to call the testview as you posted, but it shows error again shows "Unknown type name 'testView'"

Comment: did u import the testview? do #import "testView" on your view controller

Comment: Which view controller do you mean? the  original one or the new created one? I 've tried put it in the new created .m file and it said "testView files not found"

Comment: It shows the same thing in the viewController.m file when I import the testView, says that testView files not found

Comment: can you post the screenshot of your xcode project navigator and the error ? post it on imgur and paste the link here

Comment: Now I've import the testView and paste the second paragraph code in your answer into the viewController.m file but the import thing still has the same issue, and if I remove the import line then the viewDidAppeare has issue "Use of undeclared identifier" again.

Comment: do u have teamviewer?

Comment: Hi, i've upload the screen shot

Comment: remove the pasted code in view did load, and paste it below the view did load

Comment: where did u create them?

Comment: import should be #import "HouseView.h"

Comment: It compiles now!!!! But shows nothing in the ios simulator(black screen), and in the xcode shows like this: http://imgur.com/KzKlLK8

Comment: there is abreakpoint enabled at that line, remove that blue breakpoint and run your code again

Comment: Yes it now created a 3*4 grid!!

Comment: I tried change the row and col both to 18 and shows this: http://imgur.com/l3CYpyD

Comment: yes, it is beacuase the size you gave on viewDidappear is only 100,100. Change it to 400,400

Comment: Yes I tried made the view larger, where to change the size of each rects, i want to make it smaller and make the 18*18 grid full of the top half screen.

Comment: replace the value 20 wherever u see in the drawRect method with your value

Comment: My previous size was 23*23 of the rects which looks smaller than it thats why I thought its not the size parameter

Comment: but why on the top of the grids it has some texts?

Comment: it is because you draw it very top of the view controller!!! draw 20 points below!!! Chnage the code in viewdidappear from CGRectMake(30, 50, to CGRectMake(30, 70,

Comment: Thank you so much for you help, you do really help me a lot, many thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: you are welcome!!! Just take your time to analyse what you did now, and learn from it!!! Happy coding!!!

Comment: Hi, is there any method could change a specific rectangle's colour which I am going to use it as the trail after the snake passed by.

Answer (score 2):

If using iOS 9, the stacked view handles laying out a grid of view nicely:

```
NSInteger n = 15;

UIStackView *rowView = [[UIStackView alloc] init];
rowView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
rowView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal;
rowView.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionFillEqually;
[self.view addSubview:rowView];

for (NSInteger row = 0; row < n; row++) {
    UIStackView *columnView = [[UIStackView alloc] init];
    columnView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    columnView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical;
    columnView.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionFillEqually;
    [rowView addArrangedSubview:columnView];
    for (NSInteger col = 0; col < n; col++) {
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:arc4random_uniform(256) / 255.0
                                               green:arc4random_uniform(256) / 255.0
                                                blue:arc4random_uniform(256) / 255.0
                                               alpha:1.0];
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        view.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;

        [columnView addArrangedSubview:view];

        // make it it the width of the column stack view, and 1/n of the height of the column stack view

        [columnView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:columnView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth  multiplier:1 constant:0]];
        [columnView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:columnView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 / (CGFloat)n constant:0]];
    }
}

// make it square

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:rowView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:rowView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1 constant:0]];

// center it

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:rowView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:rowView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:0]];

// ensure it never exceeds 80% of the width or height of super view

NSLayoutConstraint *maxWidthConstraint  = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:rowView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth  multiplier:0.8 constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *maxHeightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:rowView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:0.8 constant:0];
[self.view addConstraints:@[maxWidthConstraint, maxHeightConstraint]];

// But have it take up 80% of either the width or height of super view

NSLayoutConstraint *preferredWidthConstraint  = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:rowView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth  multiplier:0.8 constant:0];
preferredWidthConstraint.priority = 900;
NSLayoutConstraint *preferredHeightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:rowView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:0.8 constant:0];
preferredHeightConstraint.priority = 900;
[self.view addConstraints:@[preferredWidthConstraint, preferredHeightConstraint]];
```

That yields:

[image]

If targeting earlier iOS versions, you can add build grid yourself, but it entails adding more constraints to make everything layout properly.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply I just saw this and I tried simply paste it into viewController.m file and this error shows up, and because I am very newbie to xcode so could you please help me to figure out the error? Thank you. http://imgur.com/BJHdmlK

Comment: oh I just found the problem, I put the code in the viewDidLoad and changed the row n and column n to 18, but there is another error with this: http://imgur.com/CMcgD8R I am not quite sure what value shall the n be, to suppose a 18*18 grid on the top half of the screen what shall the n be?

Comment: In my code, `n` was the size of the array (15 in my example). Use whatever variable/property you're using for the dimensions of that grid.

Comment: I've tried to changed those 3 "n" to 18 and run it, but it shows a blank screen